# Symfony 4: uploading files to a folder is not working when switching from 'dev' to 'prod'

Tags: php, symfony4

I created a function so a user can upload files for an article/finished project. These uploaded images will appear on the homepage of the website.

When I am trying to upload files to a specific folder in my development environment, it works. However if I try to upload files in the production enviroment, the files won't move to the destination folder. Is there anyone that had a similar problem/can help me out?

The code down below is the **Entity** called **Artikel** (Article in English) **Afbeeldingen** -> **Images** in English

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArtikelRepository")
 */
class Artikel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array")
     */
    private $afbeeldingen = [];

    public function getAfbeeldingen()
    {
        return $this->afbeeldingen;
    }

    public function setAfbeeldingen(array $afbeeldingen): self
    {
        $this->afbeeldingen = $afbeeldingen;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The code down below is the **services.yaml** file in which the upload directory is configured (images_directory)

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    images_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/www/uploads/artikelen'
```

The code down below is the **Controller** for the Artikel entity called **ArtikelController** (Article and ArticleController in English)

```
 /**
     * @Route("/admin/artikel/new", name="artikel_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $artikel = new Artikel();
        $form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class, $artikel);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $articleImages = $form->get('afbeeldingen')->getData();
            $images_directory = $this->getParameter('images_directory');  

            $afbeeldingen = array();
            $teller = 0;

            foreach ($articleImages as $articleImage) {
                $originalFilename = pathinfo($articleImage->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $filename = Urlizer::urlize($originalFilename) . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $articleImage->guessExtension();

                $afbeeldingen[$teller] = $filename;
                $teller += 1;

                try {
                    $articleImage->move($images_directory, $filename);
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                }
            }

            $artikel->setAfbeeldingen($afbeeldingen);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($artikel);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Artikel is aangemaakt.');


            return $this->redirectToRoute('artikel_index');
        }


        return $this->render('artikel/new.html.twig', [
            'artikel' => $artikel,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

I would be glad if someone could help me out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an empty `catch` block. Try outputting the message `catch (FileException $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); die();}`

Comment: I'd suggest referring to base namespace of PHP

    catch (\Exception $e) {
          $this->addflash('danger', '$e');  //just for debug
          return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }

Comment: I don't get any errors. If I upload the files, it will simple proceed. However, when I check the folder in which they're supposed to move, it's empty. So the route to the folder (on the domain host) is the problem. Like I mentioned in snipershadys message below, I had to change the name of the public folder to www because of the hosts default settings.

Answer (score 0):

the "www" folder is outside of the "public" folder.
You cannot access any folder outside the public.

set the service.yaml like that and try again and double-check the file system permission.

'%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/artikelen'

Comment: There are 2 folders in the root folder on my domainhost. "www" (public) and "private". The www folder contains the "uploads" folder. So I think it has to be something different then your explanation, right?

Comment: your domain host will have a virtual host pointed to one public directory, and that one is the one called "public" of your Symfony Project.
Are you trying this code in a development environment or directly from your web host?

Comment: If I try it in my development environment, it works with these settings:

parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    images_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/www/uploads/artikelen'

If I try it in my production environment/web host, it won't work with these settings. So I tried both environments. 

This might be important as well: I changed the name of my public folder to www the moment I put all my code on the web host. I changed all settings so everything is working fine except for that little piece of code.

Comment: so you did an override of the Symfony's default Directory Structure?
did you check the Exception as suggested?

Comment: Yes but that should not make sense. I tried the Exception but no message appeared.

Comment: try to write on a file from a debugController with
(just to test permission) with standard PHP function.

$fp = fopen('path/filename', 'aw);
try {
fprintf($fp, 'test write permission');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}

Comment: The only thing it then displays is: 21

Comment: print the result of fprintf "Returns the length of the string written.".... try that

Comment: So like this?: Debug::enable();

                $fp = fopen($images_directory . $filename, 'aw');
                try {
                    fprintf($fp, 'test write permission');
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo $e; exit;
                }

In the ArtikelController for example? I am a bit confused. Printf is showing nothing however, if I dump printf with dump(printf(....));exit; then it wil only show 21. So I don't really know why printf isn't working either